# Concatenate 5 unpickle dictionaries without overwriting (data is from CIFAR-10)

Tags: python, numpy

```
def unpickle(file):
import pickle
with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
    dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
return dict

dict1 = unpickle(data_dir1)
dict2 = unpickle(data_dir2)
dict3 = unpickle(data_dir3)
dict4 = unpickle(data_dir4)
dict5 = unpickle(data_dir5)
```

Data Format (from CIFAR-10):

Loaded in this way, each of the batch files contains a dictionary with the following elements:

> data -- a 10000x3072 numpy array of uint8s. Each row of the array stores a 32x32 colour image. The first 1024 entries contain the red channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024 the blue. The image is stored in row-major order, so that the first 32 entries of the array are the red channel values of the first row of the image.

My goal is to put all the numpy arrays together, which are stored in the dictionaries, as one big group of numpy arrays (no overwriting).

Comment: What do you mean by 'overwriting'?  Changing the arrays in the dictionaries, or copying data into the new big array?

Comment: I meant if two values are the same, one should not replace another. I just want to copy the data into a big array

Comment: `np.concatenate` joins `numpy` arrays.  So yes you could join the arrays from each dictionary if the dimensions match.  Nothing mysterious about that if you have some basic knowledge of numpy and array shapes.  But I still don't know what you want.  `group of numpy arrays` is vague description.  'two values are the same' is equally vague.

Comment: np.concatenate returns an error. 
 ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
Check out this link to see where the data is coming from: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.htm

Comment: That's because you are trying to concatenate the dictionaries, not the arrays contained in them!

Comment: that makes sense. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to explore,  with regular python code the nature of the `dict` objects.  If they are dictionaries, then use python dictionary methods.

Answer (score 0):

`np.concatenate((dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5), axis=0)` should work

Comment: It gave me an error:
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Comment: What does type(dict1) return? And dict1.shape?

Comment: <class 'dict'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-391b372aa98d> in <module>()
     19 
     20 print(type(dict1))
---> 21 print(dict1.shape)
     22 
     23 

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: I thought your answer mentions it was a numpy array. How is it stored inside the dict?

Comment: (https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html ) this is the link to the structure of the data